# Invalid data error in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, sqldatatypes

I have a query I am running in redshift that produces an error when I try to compare two dates. I have determined this is due to a data problem where the dates are VARCHAR and some are empty strings. The best solution is clearly to fix this at the source, but while trying to build a work around, I stumbled upon some very odd behavior.

To get around, I preselect the dates that are not empty strings, and cast as dates, then convert to integer date format (YYYYMMDD) and convert to INT. This runs fine. However, if I try to compare this with an integer in a WHERE clause, the query crashes with a data type error.

Here is a toy version of the working query

```
SELECT
    date_id,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        CONVERT(int, date_id) AS date_id
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            DATE_PART('year', start_dttm)*10000+DATE_PART('month', start_dttm)*10+DATE_PART('day', start_dttm) AS date_id
        FROM        
            (
            SELECT
                CAST(start_dttm AS DATETIME) AS start_dttm
            FROM
                sfe.calendar_detail
            WHERE
                start_dttm <> ''
            ) cda
        ) cdb
    ) cd
GROUP BY
    date_id
;
```

And here is the failed query

```
SELECT
    date_id,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        CONVERT(int, date_id) AS date_id
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            DATE_PART('year', start_dttm)*10000+DATE_PART('month', start_dttm)*10+DATE_PART('day', start_dttm) AS date_id
        FROM        
            (
            SELECT
                CAST(start_dttm AS DATETIME) AS start_dttm
            FROM
                sfe.calendar_detail
            WHERE
                start_dttm <> ''
            ) cda
        ) cdb
    ) cd
WHERE
    date_id >= 20170920
GROUP BY
    date_id
;
```

As I mentioned above, the correct solution is to fix the data type and count empty dates as Nulls not empty strings, but I am very curious as to why the second query crashes on an invalid data type error.

Many Thanks!

Edit:
Here is the error

```
ERROR:  Invalid digit, Value '1', Pos 0, Type: Integer 
DETAIL:  
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Invalid digit, Value '1', Pos 0, Type: Integer 
  code:      1207
  context:   
  query:     2006739
  location:  :0
  process:   query0_39 [pid=0]
  -----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: @500-InternalServerError the largest value is 99991231, which is less than the max that redshift doc sites 2147483647

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than converting dates to the human-readable `YYYYMMDD` format, it is always better to keep them as `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` format. This way, date operations can be easily performed (eg adding 5 days to a date). You can still do easy comparison operators by using `'YYYYMMDD'::DATE`.

Given that you are converting from a String, and casting to a Date seems to work, and that you have some empty strings, use this to convert it to a date:

```
SELECT
  NULLIF(start_dttm, '')::DATE AS dt
FROM sfe.calendar_detail
WHERE dt > '20170920'::DATE
```

This will return a NULL if the string is empty, and a Date if it contains a date that could be converted.